# Search refinement web part for SPO config for 1 sitecollection

Tags: sharepoint-online, refinement-panel

I have made a site with a template, Enterprise search center. For the site i use the webpart refinement. This works perfect with the managend properties.

The only problem, the search site works for the whole tenant but i want to use it, for only one sitecollection. I search in the settings but can't find how to config this. Is this possible?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

You can use content type Id to filter for the search feature. It will not filter whole tenant.

Code like this. It can help :

```
 Querytext: '(path:"' + this.siteUrl + '/Projects" '
            + 'path:"' + window.location.protocol + '//' + window.location.host + '/sites/Met_*")'
                + 'ContentTypeId:0x010042AB9E309341403E87FCB31F432F1DB8*'
               + ' (metProjectRoomOwnersOWSUSER:' + user.Email + ' OR metProjectRoomManagersOWSUSER:' + user.Email + ' OR metProjectRoomMembersOWSUSER:' + user.Email + ')'
```